# Which HMAC SHA Authentication should we use?

Tags: c#

I need to create HMAC hash key, but there are number of hashing functions available:
HMAC-SHA-1,
HMAC-SHA256,
HMAC-SHA384,
HMAC-SHA515

Comment: What do you need the key for?  That will likely determine any suggestions, although any answer would be opinion based to some degree.

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do and the security level you want to achieve. For good security you could use SHA-1, which in most implementations is also the fastest. However, in general it is recommended to use the SHA-2 family (SHA-224/256/384/512) for new applications over SHA-1. Also, there are implementations where on 64 bit processor architectures and for large data the more secure SHA-512 counterintuively performs much faster than the other SHA-2 algorithms due to how the calculations are done. So tl;dr would be, if you can't decide just take HMACSHA-512.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i have used SHA256.